# Run Android native code in background / terminated app

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My main idea is to receive push notifications through FCM on the Flutter side and launch a customizable notification that is on the Android native code side.
I've already managed to create my notification in the native Android code and call Flutter through MethodChannel's invokeMethod.
When the application is in the foreground, there is no problem and I can receive the push notification in real time and show the notification that is implemented in the native code.

The problem here is when the application is in the background I receive the notification data through FCM without any problems in the onBackgroundMessage method but I can't do invokeMethod to show the notification because it gives me the MissingPluginException error.

```dart
firebaseCloudMessagingListener(BuildContext context) {
    //* iOS Config
    _messaging.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));

    _messaging.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((event) {
      print('Registered: $event');
    });

    _messaging.configure(
        onBackgroundMessage: Platform.isIOS ? null : onBackgroundMessageHandler,

        //* When app is in foreground (open)
        onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
          NotificationHandler.showNotification(message['data']); //* This works
        },

        //* When app is in background
        onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {},

        //* When app is closed
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {});
  }

  static Future onBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    if (message['data'] != null) {
      dynamic data = message['data'];
      print("Receive notification in background");
      NotificationHandler.showNotification(Map<String, dynamic>.from(data)); //! This gives MissingPluginException error
    }

    return Future<void>.value();
  }
```

**Show notification method:**

```dart
static void showNotification(var message) async {
    const channel = MethodChannel('channel.luis/notifications');

    channel.invokeMethod('showNotification', {
      "title": message['title'],
      "description": message['body'],
      "type": message['ntfType'],
    });
  }
```

**LOG:**

```
I/flutter ( 4160): Receive notification in background
E/flutter ( 4160): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method showNotification on channel channel.luis/notifications)
E/flutter ( 4160): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:157
E/flutter ( 4160): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4160): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:332
E/flutter ( 4160): #2      FirebaseNotifications.onBackgroundMessageHandler
package:fact_mobile_app/firebase/firebase_notification_handler.dart:53
E/flutter ( 4160): #3      _fcmSetupBackgroundChannel.<anonymous closure>
package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart:38
E/flutter ( 4160): #4      MethodChannel._handleAsMethodCall
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:430
E/flutter ( 4160): #5      MethodChannel.setMethodCallHandler.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:383
E/flutter ( 4160): #6      _DefaultBinaryMessenger.handlePlatformMessage
package:flutter/…/services/binding.dart:283
E/flutter ( 4160): #7      _invoke3.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/hooks.dart:280:15)
E/flutter ( 4160): #8      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
E/flutter ( 4160): #9      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
E/flutter ( 4160): #10     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
E/flutter ( 4160): #11     _invoke3 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:279:10)
E/flutter ( 4160): #12     _dispatchPlatformMessage (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
E/flutter ( 4160):
```

**Can someone help me please? Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

Without looking on how you registered your MethodChannel i guess that you registered your MethodChannel in your MainActivity's configureFlutterEngine.

Problem is that when your app starts executing code while terminated like what happens with firebase's onBackgroundMessageHandler then MainActivity is not called and so your MethodChannel does not exist.

You have two options

1. Create a plugin for your native code. Could live in your project does not need to be published on pub.
2. Declare and register your MethodChannel in a custom Application class

This way you can be certain that your MethodChannel will always be available even in cases where your MainActivity has not be called yet.

Comment: Could you expand what you mean by "Declare and register your MethodChannel in a custom Application class"? If MainActivity is not called, what is then?

Comment: DId we ever get this resolved ? I am also trying to invoke some native code in my flutter background handler, and I am wondering how to "Declare and register your MethodChannel in a custom Application class"

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you use

flutter_local_notifications(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

or

awesome_notification(https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications)

plugins to pop up notification?

Especially awrsome_notification plugin offer many custom factor for your notification, for example, actionbuttons, color, icon, bigpicture, mediaplayer, progress bar, etc. But you have to know that if you want custom fcm notification, fcm message should only contain data map

Comment: Your answer does not give insight on why the op cannot call native code from their onBackgroundMessageHandler.